# Is there a program I can use to redistribute DB files across multiple volumes efficiently?

Tags: sql-server, disk-space, datafile

I'm working with a VLDB instance with over 60 DBs and close to 200 DB files, allocated over nearly 20 volumes. The instance is a Dev server getting periodic restores from a production instance with a different disk volume configuration. Since the last restore interval new DBs have been introduced and others expanded, requiring me to edit the restore scripts to specify new WITH MOVE paths. Is there a script or software package that can take the list of DB file sizes and volumes and figure out the best arrangement of the files to make the best use of each volume? The closest article pertaining to this is **[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588669/spread-objects-evenly-over-multiple-collections)**